# Probability: determining the better situation

Tags: probability, proof-verification

$\underline{\text{I am being asked to determine which claim is more accurate.}}$ Observe that claim (i) states Factory A is doing a better job than factory B and vice versa for claim (ii). The situation/claims are summarized below:

A company holds two factories (A and B) that produce two different items: 1 and 2

Factory A produces lots which consist of 1000 of **item 1** and 2000 of **item 2**

Factory B produces lots which consist of 2000 of **item 1** and 1000 of **item 2**

We are told the following:

(i) For factory A, in each lot, 2 of **item 1** and 11 of **item 2** are bad

(ii) For factory B, in each lot, 5 of **item 1** and 6 of **item 2** are bad

$\Rightarrow$ by "bad" we mean those items are useless/thrown out

$\underline{\text{Claims}}$

(i) Factory A only produces .2% bad of **item 1** and .55% **item 2** compared to .25% and .60% of Factory B (respectively). Thus Factory A does a better job of producing less bad items.

(ii) Factory B only produced 11 bad items total while A produced 13 bad ones for each lot. Thus Factory B does a better job of producing less bad items.

$\underline{\text{My Analysis}}$

I think, if at all, factory A is doing a better job (Supporting claim (i)). My thinking process is that **item 2** might have more likely hood of being bad when produced and since factory A produced more of **item 2**, it was no wonder they had more bad items. If we look at proportions (suppose each factory produced 2000 of each item), then factory A would have 4 bad of **item 1** compared to the 5 for factory B while factory B would have 12 bad of **item 2** compared to the 11 for factory A.

Is this the right way to think about this or is there anything I am missing/should take into consideration as well?

Comment: You may need to start with a definition of "better" and a theory of why bad things are produced to answer this

Comment: I made some edits to better clarify the situation. As far as a theory of "why bad things are produced," we know nothing but the statistics given. The question is asking to make assumptions based on the numbers (like two points of view) of the situation. This is from a book, so I assume we should be able to come up with a correct conclusion.